# Marshmallow generating dict representation of schema

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, deserialization, marshmallow

Is there any way to generate dict representation of schema from a standard class schema?

I have a schema

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from marshmallow.validate import Length


class ArtistSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(validate=[Length(3)])
    age = fields.Int(required=True)
```

And I want to generate a dict-representation of that schema:

```
schema_as_dict = {
    "name": {
        "min_length": 3
    },
    "age": {
        "required": True
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Comment: What is `Schema` and what are `fields`? Not everyone know what they should be. I for one don't know what they are. I haven't used `marshmallow` before. Please add the necessary imports. And your problem is simple, just look at `ArtistSchema.__dict__` (and `__dict__` of its attributes, too).

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Yeah thanks, I forgot to add imports. They are there now. Standard __dict__ or marshmallow functions are working, but they are too much descriptive. I would prefer a dict representation of that schema, but only with values setted manually, something that wotks like "if required of field is set to True, then add this information to dict description" without rest of unnecessary informations

Comment: i have never used marshmallow before, but what prevents you from extracting the required data and constructing the dict yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted, but this should do.

I just poked around `ArtistSchema.__dict__`, and found the `_declared_fields` attribute which contains information about the fields:

```
In [115]: ArtistSchema._declared_fields
Out[115]:
{'name': <fields.String(dump_default=<marshmallow.missing>, attribute=None, validate=[<Length(min=3, max=None, equal=None, error=None)>], required=False, load_only=False, dump_only=False, load_default=<marshmallow.missing>, allow_none=False, error_messages={'required': 'Missing data for required field.', 'null': 'Field may not be null.', 'validator_failed': 'Invalid value.', 'invalid': 'Not a valid string.', 'invalid_utf8': 'Not a valid utf-8 string.'})>,
 'age': <fields.Integer(dump_default=<marshmallow.missing>, attribute=None, validate=None, required=True, load_only=False, dump_only=False, load_default=<marshmallow.missing>, allow_none=False, error_messages={'required': 'Missing data for required field.', 'null': 'Field may not be null.', 'validator_failed': 'Invalid value.', 'invalid': 'Not a valid integer.', 'too_large': 'Number too large.'})>}
```

It is a dictionary, we can traverse through it by looping through its items view. The keys are the names of fields and values are information about the fields.

I then inspected the `__dict__` of the field information:

```
In [148]: ArtistSchema._declared_fields['name'].__dict__
Out[148]:
{'dump_default': <marshmallow.missing>,
 'load_default': <marshmallow.missing>,
 'attribute': None,
 'data_key': None,
 'validate': [<Length(min=3, max=None, equal=None, error=None)>],
 'validators': [<Length(min=3, max=None, equal=None, error=None)>],
 'allow_none': False,
 'load_only': False,
 'dump_only': False,
 'required': False,
 'metadata': {},
 'error_messages': {'required': 'Missing data for required field.',
  'null': 'Field may not be null.',
  'validator_failed': 'Invalid value.',
  'invalid': 'Not a valid string.',
  'invalid_utf8': 'Not a valid utf-8 string.'}}
```

You probably don't want `dump_default`, `load_default`, `validate`, `validators` and `error_messages`. Many of the other attributes are falsy and we can just ignore the attributes that are falsy. That said, `validators` contains information about the field you declared, so we need to process it too.

We can simply use `_declared_fields` to get the fields, loop through the items and loop through the `__dict__` of the field information, ignore all unwanted keys and falsy values, to get the required information. If there are validators, get information about them in the same manner.

Code:

```
import re
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from marshmallow.validate import Length


class ArtistSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(validate=[Length(3)])
    age = fields.Int(required=True)


def parse_schema(schema):
    return {
        "schema_name": schema.__name__,
        "schema_fields": {
            field: {
                name: attr
                for name, attr in field_data.__dict__.items()
                if not re.search("default|error|valid", name) and attr
            }
            | {
                k: v
                for validator in field_data.validators
                for k, v in validator.__dict__.items()
                if v
            }
            | {"type": type(field_data)}
            for field, field_data in schema._declared_fields.items()
        },
    }
```

Output:

```
{'schema_name': 'ArtistSchema',
 'schema_fields': {'name': {'min': 3, 'type': marshmallow.fields.String},
  'age': {'required': True, 'type': marshmallow.fields.Integer}}}
```